# Making a quiz to ask random questions in python from csv file

Tags: python, csv, random, split, import-from-csv

I need help making this function be able to ask a random question from column 1 in my CSV and cross reference it with the same row but column 2 to see if it is correct. Here's what I have:

```
import random

def playerTriviaQuestions():
    fo = open("playerstriviaquestions.csv","r")
    players = fo.readlines()
    for p in players:
        data = p.split(",")
    questions = data[0]
    answers = data[1]
    print(questions)

    fo.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.

You can use [random.choice()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to select a random line from the `players` list.
Use the [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function to get input from the user.

Then you just need to use the `==` operator to check if the answer is correct.

I would also recommend using the `with` statement to make the file automatically close.

Comment: figured it out using that random.choice. Thanks!